# Counterexample: $G \times K \cong H \times K \implies G \cong H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

I am having a hard time finding a counterexample for the statement:
$G \times K \cong H \times K \implies G \cong H$

I think this should be true for abelian, finite groups. But is this true in general? What would be a counterexample?

Any hints appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I just corrected it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $G = \mathbb{Z} $, $H = \{1\}$, $K = \displaystyle\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Your counterexample still holds if you take $G = \{1\}$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}$ right?

Comment: Oh right, that would simplify it.

Comment: @IsaacSolomon, I am curious, if $G$ is finite and neither $H$ nor $K$ is trivial, would this be true?

Comment: Let $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $H = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $K = \displaystyle\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'm using the wrong notation. Let me edit it. What I mean is the group with 2 elements.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I think I mislead you also. I was meant to say $G\times K$ is finite. I think it is true in that case.

Comment: Well, that's going to imply that $G$ and $K$ are finite, so that $H$ is also finite. I don't know the answer in that case.

Comment: I found a proof that showed the statement is true for H, K and G finite and abelian, but shouldn't it be true regardless whether the H, G are abelian or not?

Comment: @misi, maybe this problem is not so easy. I am not convinced with myself, I will start a question.

Answer (score 14):

The other two examples are both infinitely generated. However, in group theory the trick is often do prove results for *finitely generated* or (even better!) *finitely presented* groups. Here, we want to show that there exists finitely presented groups $A, B, C, C^{\prime}$ such that $A\times C\cong B\times C^{\prime}$, $C\cong C^{\prime}$ but $A\not\cong B$. (I know that this will go way, way over your head @misi, but this was bugging me all morning. Infinitely generated groups are not necessarily cancellable (by the answers to this question), while finite groups are (by the answers to [a spin-off question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349855/does-g-times-k-cong-h-times-k-imply-g-cong-h)). I wanted to find out where the breaking point was.)

A group $Q$ is cancellable if $A\times Q\cong B\times Q\Rightarrow A\cong B$ (for any $A$).

The following example proves that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not cancellable in general, and can be found in [R. Hirshon, On Cancellation in Groups, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 76, No. 9 (Nov., 1969), pp. 1037-1039]. I should point out before we start that it seems Hirshon is rather non-committal about this result. He uses the word "may" throughout. The infinite cyclic group *may* not be cancellable in general. I wonder if he is just saying that it isn't cancellable in general so you may not be able to cancel it? I am not sure. Certainly, I cannot see where his proof fails. It is, essentially, a complete proof! (I have pointed out the bit which is not in his proof, and have filled it in.)

Let $H$ be the group given by the presentation $\langle a, y; a^{-1}ya=y^4, y^{1024}=y\rangle$.

Things to note:

- $H=C_{1024}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$. That is, $H$ is a semidirect product of the infinite cyclic group with the cyclic group of order $1024$ by the automorphism $\phi: y\mapsto y^4$.
- $a^5$ centralises $y$. That is, $a^{-5}ya^5=y$.
- $K=\langle a^2, y\rangle$ is *not* isomorphic to $H$. Note that the group $K$ is still a semidirect product, but the automorphism is now not $\phi$. The fact that $K$ and $H$ are not isomorphic follows, for example, from Proposition 2.1 of [this paper](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~arjantseva/Abs/isom.pdf). (Note: Hirshon does not prove that these groups are non-isomorphic. I wonder if this is what he was being cagey about?)
- Hirshon wants you to realise that $2\cdot 2-1\cdot 5$ has absolute value $1$.

Now, for $\langle z\rangle$ an infinite cyclic group take $G=H\times\langle z\rangle$. Write $w=z^2a^5$ and $M=\langle za^2, y\rangle$. Note that $M\cong K\not\cong H$ (why?). Then, $G\cong M\times\langle w\rangle$, and we have proven that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not cancellable in general.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Let
$$K = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \cdots$$
be countably many copies of $\mathbb Z$.