# Does $A\oplus \mathbb{Z}\cong B\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ imply $A\cong B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, direct-sum

If $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups, do we have that $A\oplus \mathbb{Z}\cong B\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ implies $A\cong B$?

Motivation: I was just thinking about different ways of deducing equality from expressions by quotienting, then realized I didn't know the answer in this case.

Comment: In which context did this question arise?

Comment: I was just thinking about different ways of deducing equality from expressions by quotienting, then realized I didn't know the answer in this case.

Comment: If $A, B$ are finitely generated, then it follows by the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: Sorted. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

[Cohn](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1956-007-03/S0002-9939-1956-0078370-X/S0002-9939-1956-0078370-X.pdf) and [Walker](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2033557) showed independently in 1956 that, if $A,B,C$ are abelian groups, $C$ is finitely generated, and $A\oplus C \cong B\oplus C$, then $A\cong B$.

This is sometimes called "Walker's cancellation theorem", though Cohn's proof in particular looks very short.  The one-paragraph Section 3 handles the case $C=\mathbb{Z}$ specifically.

---

Cohn, Paul M. "The complement of a finitely generated direct summand of an abelian group." Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 7.3 (1956): 520-521.

Walker, Elbert A. "Cancellation in direct sums of groups." Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 7.5 (1956): 898-902.

Comment: For $C = \Bbb Z$, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/349960) answer may be interesting to read.

Comment: The links are dead. What are the publications?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Updated with a fresh link and citations. Impressively, the results were in the same publication!