# $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus A \implies \mathbb{Z}\cong A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-module and suppose that $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus A$. Do we have $\mathbb{Z}\cong A$?

I know the result is true if $A$ is finitely generated as $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Clearly, $A$ can be viewed as a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

Maybe a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is finitely generated?

Comment: Just a comment about your last question. The module $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is noetherian (it's finitely generated over a noetherian ring). Hence any submodule of $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is finitely generated

Comment: In fact, it is more generally true that if $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups and $\mathbb{Z}\oplus A\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus B$, then $A\cong B$. See, for example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485723/does-a-oplus-mathbbz-cong-b-oplus-mathbbz-imply-a-cong-b/1485954#1485954), although the case $B=\mathbb{Z}$ that you ask about is easier than the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Bbb Z \oplus A$ is finitely generated, then $A$ must be finitely generated. So, it indeed holds that if $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z \cong \Bbb Z \oplus A$, then $A$ is finitely generated and your previous observation applies. So, $A \cong \Bbb Z$.

Comment: And why exactly is A finitely generated? In general submodules of finitely generated modules need not be finitely generated right?

Comment: To be explicit, if $(n_1,a_1),\cdots,(n_k,a_k)$ generate $\mathbb{Z}\oplus A$, then $a_1,\cdots,a_k$ generate $A$.

Comment: @user745578: Though subgroups of f.g. modules need not be f.g., *quotients* do; and $A$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus A$.

Comment: More generally, the if a f.g. module surjects onto another module, that module is also f.g. (its generators being the images of the original generators under the surjection). So, in particular, any direct summand of a f.g. module is f.g. by virtue of the projection map.