# Cancellation property for direct products

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

I must be misunderstanding something very elementary, because every proof I see of this uses advanced methods (including the one in my course notes). Suppose $G, H, K$ are groups such that $G \times H \cong G \times K$. We have to prove that $K \cong H$. Now we know $G \times \{ 1 \} $ is a normal subgroup of the direct product, so we can cancel it out. By the second isomorphism theorem we obtain:

$(G \times H)/G \times \{ 1 \} \cong (G \times \{ 1 \})(\{ 1 \} \times H)/G \times \{ 1 \} \cong \{ 1 \} \times H$

and likewise for $K$. Consequently, $\{ 1 \} \times K \cong \{ 1 \} \times H$ and $K \cong H$.

What is wrong with this proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error here is that you are assuming the two copies of $G$ in your group are the *same* subgroup, rather than different-but-isomorphic subgroups.

The result you claim is not true in general; you need to assume that the groups are e.g. [finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/427640/10513). For example, it does not hold even if the groups are all finitely presented and $G\cong\mathbb{Z}$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/349960/10513)).

Comment: So it does hold for finite groups? Because in my textbook the proof for finite groups is a very convoluted affair using category theory. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've added some links, including to an elementary proof of the case when all the groups are finite.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 4):

While it is true that $G\times H/H\cong G\times K/K$, this in no way implies that $H\cong K$. In fact, this cancellation property you are speaking of is simply not true. Take $G=\prod\limits_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z},\ H=\mathbb{Z},\ K=\mathbb{Z\times Z.}$