# example for $K\rtimes H\cong G\rtimes H$ and $K\ncong G$

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, group-actions, group-isomorphism, semidirect-product

Let $H,L$ be groups acting on $K,G$. Show that $K\rtimes H\cong G\rtimes L$ and $K\ncong G$ is not true in general.

I found a solution online using $\times$:
[Counterexample: $G \times K \cong H \times K \implies G \cong H$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349826/counterexample-g-times-k-cong-h-times-k-implies-g-cong-h) .
I know the following: If $\{1\}\rtimes H \trianglelefteq K \rtimes H$ it follows that $K \rtimes H=K \times H.$ So am I right that this solutions works for my problem as well if $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\{1\}$ are acting trivial on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times...$?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, the duplicate also gives an example for your title question, by just taking the trivial semidirect product.

Comment: Shaun, I think you messed up the subject line. The subject line right now is silly; what the OP wanted was an example where this happened, not an example that it *didn't*.

Comment: At the moment the title and the question both look silly. I can take $H,L,K,G$ to be random completely unrelated groups with trivial actions, and then $K \rtimes H \cong G \rtimes L$ is very unlikely to be true!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, @ArturoMagidin; I'm not sure how to fix it. I'll leave it to you if that's alright.

Comment: $\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$If you wish to see an example where both semidirect products are non-trivial, you may consider the dihedral group of order $8$, say $D = \Span{ (1234), (13)} = \Set{1, (1234), (13)(24), (1432), (13), (24), (12)(34), (14)(23)}$. Then take $K = \Set{1, (13)(24), (12)(34), (14)(23)}$, $G = \Span{(1234)} = \Set{1, (1234), (13)(24), (1432)}$, $H = \Span{(13)} = \Set{1, (13)}$. One has $D = K \rtimes H = G \rtimes H$, but $K \not\cong G$.